# Update ElasticSearch when DELETE with ZOMBODB

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch

I follow the tutorial on GitHub (https://github.com/zombodb/zombodb/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) to use ZOMBO DB on PostgreSQL. Everything works perfectly. When I search on my Elastic Search I've got all the data. All the INSERT and UPDATE. The only problem is that I don't have the DELETE on my Elastic. When I delete a row in my Psql, Elastic doesn't receive the information. 
I arrived to refresh Elastic's data with VACUUM FREEZE but it's a manual operation. Do you have a solution? 
Thanks for your answer.

Ambroise

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Zombo send the information (DELETE) to Elastica. The attribute 'zdb_max' update on the index after delete is done in pgsql. So it's possible to filter my query. But Elastic still got the index. So i still need to Vacuum my table. Somebody got an idea to do that with a another solution.

Thanks